# Flutter - Image doesn't show at all inside FlatButton

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a circular-image-button. To do this, I put a FlatButton inside a container, an image as the button's child.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'User info',
                style: Constants.HEADING_STYLE,
              ),
              Container(
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: getImageWidget(imageUrl),
                  shape: new CircleBorder(),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() async {
                      imageUrl = await uploadImage();                  
                    });
                  },
                ),
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
              ),
              Form(
                key: _nameFormKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget> [
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Username',
                      ),
                      validator: validateName,
                      onChanged: (name) { this.username = name;},
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Next'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  isUnique = await isUsernameUnique(username);

                  if(_nameFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    saveUserName();
                  }
                } ,               
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Widget getImageWidget(imagePath) {
  if(imagePath == null || imagePath == "") {
    return FittedBox(
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage('assets/no_image.png'),
      ),
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    );
  } else {
    return FittedBox(
      child: Image.network(
        imagePath,
      ),
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    );
  }
}
```

But for some reason, the image doesn't appear at all. The button however is the right shape and responds on holding and tapping. I tried moving the image directly into the column, but it still doesn't show. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a `CircleAvator` with a `InkWell` widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CircleImageButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => print("you have tapped on image"),
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://storage.googleapis.com/dev-dot-ai-project-ic.appspot.com/1/2019/03/demo.jpg"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note that you are doing a bad thing when your image button tapped, Dont ever make `setState` `async`.

FlatButton might not be the best solution because it has a button theme with padding and other material styles. You can create your custom button that will give you more flexibity.

If you still need to use `FlatButton`, you can remove `FittedBox`(Its throwing some errors when restart) and do as below (this can add to any gesture widget):

```
  Widget getImageWidget(imagePath) {
    if (imagePath == null || imagePath == "") {
      return buildCircularImage(AssetImage('assets/no_image.png'));
    } else {
      return buildCircularImage(NetworkImage(imagePath));
    }
  }

  Widget buildCircularImage(ImageProvider provider) {
    return Container(
      width: 70,
      height: 70,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: provider,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If you want you can use FloatingActionButton. But notice that same above snippet implementation is here:

import 'pack

```
age:flutter/material.dart';

class FloatingImageButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => print("button tapped"),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage("https://storage.googleapis.com/dev-dot-ai-project-ic.appspot.com/1/2019/03/demo.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover
          ),
          ),
        ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

There are other approach to this also.